# NSCollectionViewItem's custom view flickers onReloadData

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, calayer, nscollectionview

I have a `NSCollectionViewItem` with a custom view, in that view I am adding custom `CALayer` to some items. On button action, I am calling `NSCollectionView`'s `reloadData()` method to reload the different data. This causes the custom `CALayer` to flicker as the item changes. Any idea how to fix it?

Adding `CALayer` to item's view based on some condition

```
circleLayer = CALayer();
let dimension = floor(min(bounds.width, bounds.height) - 10);
circleLayer.frame = NSMakeRect(4.5, 4, dimension, dimension);
circleLayer.cornerRadius = dimension / 2;
backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 84/255, green: 84/255, blue: 87/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor;
circleLayer.masksToBounds = false;
circleLayer.isHidden = false;
layer?.addSublayer(circleLayer);
```

Function called on button click

```
//loading different data
collectionView.reloadData();
```

So as the button is clicked the background color of some other item changes, but the background color of previous item flickers. I guess this probably due to reuse of `NSCOllectionViewItem`. How can I avoid this? Any idea?

Comment: What happens if you try to reload the data without animation?
Something like this: ```UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }```

Comment: @Prientus i dont think `performWithoutAnimation` is available on **macOS**. Also the data is not being reloaded with animation.

Comment: @Prientus you were right. I was able to fix the issue by calling `NSAnimationContext.current().duration = 0` just before `collectionView.reloadData();`

Comment: Glad that worked! :)